# Is Coroutine job auto cancelled upon exiting Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I have the below code of a slow loading image

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var job: Job

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(this)
            .componentRegistry { add(SvgDecoder(this@MainActivity)) }
            .build()

        job = MainScope().launch {
            try {
                val request = ImageRequest.Builder(this@MainActivity)
                    .data("https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg")
                    .build()
                val drawable = imageLoader.execute(request).drawable
                Log.d("TrackLog", "Loaded")
                findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.my_view).setImageDrawable(drawable)
            } catch (e: CancellationException) {
                Log.d("TrackLog", "Cancelled job")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
//        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

If I exit the activity before the image loaded completed, I thought I should manually perform `job.cancel()` to get the coroutine canceled.

However, even when I commented out the `job.cancel()`, the job still get canceled when I exit `MainActivity`.

This is also true when I use either `GlobalScope` or even use a global variable scope and job.

```
val myScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
private lateinit var job: Job

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(this)
            .componentRegistry { add(SvgDecoder(this@MainActivity)) }
            .build()

        job = myScope.launch {
            try {
                val request = ImageRequest.Builder(this@MainActivity)
                    .data("https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg")
                    .build()
                val drawable = imageLoader.execute(request).drawable
                Log.d("TrackLog", "Loaded")
                findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.my_view).setImageDrawable(drawable)
            } catch (e: CancellationException) {
                Log.d("TrackLog", "Cancelled job")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
//        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

I'm puzzled how did the job get canceled when we exit the Activity even when I don't call `job.cancel()`.

Comment: Yes unless you start coroutine as `launch(NonCancellable) {}`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, because my `request` is made of `this@MainActivity`

```
                val request = ImageRequest.Builder(this@MainActivity)
                    .data("https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg")
                    .build()
```

hence, when exiting, the `this@MainActivity` is killed, hence the `request` also got terminated and perhaps canceled?

If we use `baseContext`

```
                val request = ImageRequest.Builder(baseContext)
                    .data("https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg")
                    .build()
```

then we have to manually cancel the job during `onDestroy`

Therefore it is always safer to use `lifecycleScope`